# Sql Server Statement to calculate accommodation utilisation

Tags: sql-server, select, percentage

I want to calculate the total number of Occupied accommodation as a percentage of the total accommodtion available. I am using the query below. I dont think the query is right. It returns error near From.
Please can anyone help

```sql
SELECT ((COUNT(Accommodation.dbo.House.HouseID) / COUNT(B.HouseID)) * 100) AS [Accommodation Utilisation %]
FROM (SELECT COUNT(B.HouseID)
      FROM Accommodation.dbo.House B
      WHERE Accommodation.dbo.House.STATUS = 'Occupied')
FROM Accommodation.dbo.House
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided (4 part naming for columns certainly should be). You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Your query has 2 `FROM`s in the same scope; that isn't allowed. Your derived table is also  lacking an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a much easier way to do this would be to use a conditional `AVG`:

```sql
SELECT AVG(CASE H.STATUS WHEN 'Occupied' THEN 1. ELSE 0. END) AS Utilisation --Don't use names that need to be delimit identified.
FROM dbo.House H; --You should already be connnected to the database Accomodation, so it doesn't need to appear here
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd6c5bb2588f9427f6e6e5fe5fb71aa3)

Comment: Brilliant. It worked. Thanks a lot. Please, How do I express the result as a percentage

Comment: Larnu. Thanks once more. I was able to format it to %. this way. SELECT FORMAT((AVG(CASE H.STATUS WHEN 'Occupied' THEN 1. ELSE 0. END)),'P0') as [WholeNumberPercentage]
FROM Accommodation.dbo.House H;

Comment: Formatting is for the presentation layer, not the SQL layer, @CAwaibe .